# What do you need to do to get the Tenacious badge?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I've just got myself the tenacious badge! Way-hey!! Errrr what did I do, to get it again??

The Tenacious badge is defined as: Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total. Can anyone elaborate on this? More than 5 what? Questions? Points answers? and 20% of what total? Calories burnt today?

Comment: Answer questions that were asked by users that don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up :-) P.S. Belongs on meta.

Comment: There's information about badges [on the main Help section](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/badges)

Answer (score 4):

It means that of your accepted answers, you have more than five with zero score and those zero-score accepted answers are more than 20% of the total number of answers.

I'm not entirely sure why this question is on Meta.UX, because your Tenacious badge is on Stack Overflow. Anyway, you have 48 answers; 31 of those are zero-score; and 10 zero-score answers are accepted.

20% of 48 is 9.6 — you now have 10 accepted zero-score answers which is more than five and more than 9.6.